# How to open `modal window` from the header controller to main controller using service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have couple of links in the header. But the `pop-up` nested under the other controller. I am using a service call for the `pop-up` here.

clicking on the header link, how can i open the `pop-up` which nested in the other controller.

And i need to update the content of the `pop-up` according to the link what the user clicks. for that, i included the html (using `ng-include`)

here is my code and demo :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.service('modalService', function() {
      this.width  = 100;
      this.height  = 100;
  });

  app.directive('modalDialog', function(modalService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


    },
    templateUrl: "modal.html"
  };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',  function($scope, modalService) {
  $scope.modalShown = false;
}]); 

app.controller('header', ['$scope', 'modalService', function($scope, modalService) {

  $scope.modalShown = false;

  $scope.toggleModal = function(link) {
    console.log(link);
    $scope.linkInfo = link+'.html';
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  };

}]);
```

[Live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xn2LTCQdtdeAZiRfzTOy?p=preview)

In case the way what i do is wrong, please correct me. at present the fuction is calls and gettting console.  but pop-up not opening with appropriate content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modal service of angular-UI library [angular-ui#modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

If you want to just create something simple, you have to change your code in following ways:

1. I would recommend using ngIf for showing/hiding your modalDialog directive. With it, it will be rendered when the expression becomes truthy and you can get the right template each time.
2. Do not transclude since you don't have static templates. You have to compile the template on runtime (using $compile service). Also create a new scope for that template.

   ```
   app.directive('modalDialog', function(modalService, $rootScope, $compile, $templateCache) {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
         show: '=',
         templateUrl: '='
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var template = $templateCache.get(scope.templateUrl);
         var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
         var modalElement = angular.element(template);

         element.append(modalElement);
         $compile(modalElement)(modalScope);

       },
       templateUrl: "modal.html"
     };
   });
   ```

   Note that there are still issues. Your placing of modal into arbitrary location into a DOM may not work (not all browsers behave correctly when playing with positioning). So I would recommend creating a service that would append and render the modal just below the  element.

Comment: Here is my try: can you tell me if this wrong : http://plnkr.co/edit/xn2LTCQdtdeAZiRfzTOy?p=preview

Comment: The biggest problem I see there at the moment is, that you have the logic for modal all over the place. Concentrate it only in a single place. For that I recomment using isolated scope on the directive see [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). In your case add: `scope: { width: '=', height: '=', templateUrl: '=' }` to your directive definition.  I would also move the showing/hiding of the modal out of the directive and now you can also delete the modal service (since you do not need it to share the state any more)